# Supporting uniform/non-uniform scale in hierarchical animation

Tags: animation, scale, blending, hierarchy

I have worked with hierarchical blended animation systems for a number of years, but I have never been quite sure how to handle scale correctly. The introduction of non-uniform scale is additionally puzzling. Does anyone have any insight into the right way of doing it? What I am trying to determine is when in the hierarchical concatenation that scale is included. My components are stored as a follows:

```
vector3 position;
vector3 scale;
quaternion rotation;
quaternion stretch_rotation;
```

What I am finding is if I include scale into the matrix during concatenation, I run the risk of grossly amplifying the accumulated errors down the hierarchy. Does anyone have any insight or articles here? To be clear - I know how to do hierarchical animation just not the right way to handle scale.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, in running through the hierarchy, you could multiply scalar scales for each separate axis, to get the distinct world-space scale for each separate axis. Unity's `Transform` calls this(?) `lossyScale`, and presumably because it is generated by multiplying the individual axes' scale all the way up the hierarchy, as I recommend, it is a `readonly` member. One can change the local scale at each level up the tree, individually. [The brief doc for their implementation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-lossyScale.html)
may be informative.